# Use JQ to generate CSV from knife search

Tags: csv, jq, chef

JQ looks like a great tool, but I'm struggling with it. Here is what I am trying to do:
Extract just the values from this chef knife search and generate a CSV.

given this command and output:

> knife search node "name:foo*" -a name -a cpu.total -a memory.total -Fj

```
{
  "results": 2,
  "rows": [
    {
      "foo-01": {
        "name": "foo-01",
        "cpu.total": 12,
        "memory.total": "16267368kB"
      }
    },
    {
      "foo-02": {
        "name": "foo-02",
        "cpu.total": 12,
        "memory.total": "16264296kB"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to get the values extracted to CSV like this:

```
foo-01,12,16267368kB
foo-02,12,16264296kB
```

(I can deal with the quotes)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
... | jq -r '.rows[] | .[] | [.name, .["cpu.total"], .["memory.total"]] | map(tostring) | join(",")'
```

This:

1. [Expands the array](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Array/ObjectValueIterator:.[]) in `.rows` into the output stream (`.rows.[]`).
2. [Pipes that stream](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Pipe:%7C) into the next step (`|`).
3. Expands the object it's given into the (in this case) single value it contained (`.[]`).
4. [Creates an array](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/Arrayconstruction:[]) with the results of `.name`, `.["cpu.total"]`, and `.["memory.total"]` [each evaluated on that object](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Comma:,) (`.[ .name, ... ]`).
5. [Converts all the values](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#map(x),map_values(x)) of that array [into strings](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#tostring) (`map(tostring)`).
6. [Joins the elements](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#join(str)) of each array with a comma (`join(",")`).

[`jq -r` outputs raw data](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Invokingjq), rather than quoting and escaping it. The output is then:

```
foo-01,12,16267368kB
foo-02,12,16264296kB
```

as you wanted. Depending on your CSV parser & the real data, you might need extra quoting around the strings, which you can add in, [or use `@csv`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Formatstringsandescaping) in place of the last two steps.

```
... | jq -r '.rows[] | .[] | [.name, .["cpu.total"], .["memory.total"]] | @csv'
```

---

We could skip the `map` by converting only the one value inside, which takes some extra brackets:

```
... | jq -r '.rows[]|.[]|[.name, (.["cpu.total"] | tostring), .["memory.total"]] | join(",")'
```

And probably the ugliest alternative:

```
... | jq -r '.rows[]|to_entries|.[]|.key + "," + (.value["cpu.total"] | tostring) + "," + .value["memory.total"]'
```

In this case, we don't rely on the `.name` field, and build up the whole string manually. If you need a highly customised format, this is the most flexible option.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer and explanation. I was initially having problems figuring out how to access the fields with dots in the name, I see now how you have to quote them.

Answer (score 3):

There's probably a "rule of the universe" that says something like "as soon as you post a question to SE, the answer will come to you"... Shortly after posting this question, I persisted with a try/google/rtfm loop, and eventually came up with this that worked for me:

```
knife search node "name:foo*" -a name -a cpu.total -a memory.total -Fj | jq -r '.rows[] | map(.[]) | @csv '
```

Which returns:

```
"foo-01",12,"16267000kB"
"foo-02",12,"16267000kB"
```

This imports cleanly right into google sheets. I can probably tweak that even further with some of the examples Michael gave. I kinda prefer this, because I don't have to specify the field names explicitly.
Looking forward to playing more with JQ, what a great tool!

Comment: The trouble here is that I don't think you're guaranteed to get the fields in the right (perhaps even same) order - that's why I listed out the names. I'm not entirely certain about that though, and it might work in this case anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The `jq` expression

```
.rows[] | map(.[]) | @csv
```

in [your own answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/381149/116858) is neat, but taking [Michael's concern](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/381052/use-jq-to-generate-csv-from-knife-search#comment677093_381149) about the ordering of the keys into account, you may want to instead explicitly extract the values that you need:

```
.rows[][] | [ .name, ."cpu.total", ."memory.total" ] | @csv
```

or,

```
.rows[] | map( .name, ."cpu.total", ."memory.total" ) | @csv
```